# What's the best way to solve this Java inheritance dilema?

Tags: java, inheritance

First a Car class:

```
public class Car {

    private final Engine engine;

    public Car(int x, int y) {

      this.engine = createEngine(x, y);

      // (...)
    }

    protected Engine createEngine(int x, int y) {
         return new Engine(x ,y);
    }
}
```

Now I want to create a FastCar, that will need a FastEngine, not just an Engine.

```
public class FastEngine extends Engine {

    public FastEngine(int x, int y, double a, double b) {
        super(x, y);
        // (...)
    }

    // (...)
}

public class FastCar extends Car {

    private final double a;
    private final double b;

    public FastCar(int x, int y, double a, double b) {
        super(x, y);
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    protected Engine createEngine(int x, int y) {
        // of course I can't use a and b here, they were not initialized yet :( :( :(
        return new FastEngine(x, y /* I need a and b here too :( */);
    }
}
```

So the problem is that on my new FastCar class, I need to switch the Engine for a FastEngine, but the FastEngine now takes arguments a and b passed in the constructor. It looks like I hit a dead end, what can I do besides rewriting everything from scratch with a new entity model?

Comment: @shmosel "_I can't use a and b here, they were not initialized yet... What? Why not?_" - if you did not see that then we have a problem :P

Comment: @CyrusLeung You got this wrong unfortunately :(

Comment: I see now. It's never a good idea to call instance methods from a constructor. Consider constructing the engine outside.

Comment: @shmosel Agree, but unfortunately the engine does need to be constructed in the constructor. I **cannot** have a method nowCreateEngine() that I would call after the Car is created :/

Comment: Why? What are the requirements exactly?

Comment: I agree with shmosel. Don't construct your engine using an instance method from the constructor. This would be better solved with Dependency Injection. Just inject the engine you want in your constructor.

Comment: I think this is a simple case of the http://xyproblem.info/. Tell us what problem you are trying to solve rather than a contrived example and we might be able to help you more.

Comment: @Josh, that's definitely the wrong way to act on this site. I see you are new contributor, so I'll not flag you for it this time, but you need to be conscious of when people are asking for clarifying information. Your problem is simply solved by doing what we've already told you to do. Now if your problem is actually a different problem and can't be solved that way, then you should edit your question to clarify.

Comment: That's how the code that I'm working on looks like... I can't change the world for you guys, I'm sorry.

Comment: You haven't explained _why_ the code is that way. It doesn't matter if that's what it currently looks like. It's a bad idea. We can't help you with a good solution if you don't give us more information.

Comment: Josh, I'm going to refer you to [this document](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct). Go there, read it, think about it, then come back here and work with us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I do agree with the comments that the question is not well formulated, I'll give you the solution. Feel free to add generics to make it more beautiful.

```
public class Car {

    static class CarConfig {
        int x;
        int y;

        CarConfig(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }

    private final Engine engine;

    public Car(int x, int y) {

      this(new CarConfig(x, y));
    }

    Car(CarConfig config) {
         this.engine = createEngine(config);
    }

    protected Engine createEngine(CarConfig config) {
         return new Engine(config.x ,config.y);
    }
}
```

Then in your subclass:

```
public class FastEngine extends Engine {

    public FastEngine(int x, int y, double a, double b) {
        super(x, y);
        // (...)
    }

    // (...)
}

public class FastCar extends Car {

    static class FastCarConfig extends CarConfig {
         double a;
         double b;

         FastCarConfig(int x, int y, double a, double b) {
             super(x, y);
             this.a = a;
             this.b = b;
         }
     }


    private final double a;
    private final double b;

    public FastCar(int x, int y, double a, double b) {
        super(new FastCarConfig(x, y, a, b);
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    protected Engine createEngine(CarConfig config) {
        if (config instanceof FastCarConfig) throw new IllegalStateException("You messed up!");
        FastCarConfig c = (FastCarConfig) config;
        return new FastEngine(c.x, c.y, c.a, c.b);
    }
}
```

**B O O M !**

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to create an Engine Factory. Remember the "[Single Responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)" principle ([SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)).

In the real life you don't build the engine inside the car. You do it separately. Sometimes on another factory. The engine is being fitted in the car on the assembly line.

This gives you more flexibility both - on the factory and in the code.

Going further I suggest to implement a [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) - if you'll have more parts fitted into the car.

P.s. ignore "static"s - I just added them to avoid IDE warnings.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Car car = new Car(EngineFactory.createEngine(1, 2));
    Car fastCar = new FastCar(EngineFactory.createEngine(1, 2, 1d, 2d), 1d, 2d);
}

static class EngineFactory{
    public static Engine createEngine(int x, int y){
        return new Engine(x, y);
    }

    public static Engine createEngine(int x, int y, double a, double b){
        return new FastEngine(x, y, a, b);
    }
}

public static class Car {
    private final Engine engine;
    public Car(Engine engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }
}

public static class FastCar extends Car {

    private final double a;
    private final double b;

    public FastCar(Engine engine, double a, double b) {
        super(engine);
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}

public static class FastEngine extends Engine {
    public FastEngine(int x, int y, double a, double b) {
        super(x, y);
    }
}

public static class Engine{
    int x;
    int y;

    public Engine(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's another solution, although I think I would prefer, as the user of this API, to create the car without having to create its parts too, like the answer with CarConfig. Imagine if I had to create a car and pass each component of the car on its contructor?

Comment: In that case you can just create a Car Static Factory with simple methods. They will call car construction by parts. This will be transparent for the API user but it will add flexibility to the code and allow to create reusable base car builders and types.

Answer (score 1):

Move the engine consruction back into the car constructor. If creating the engines takes more than a constructor call move it to a static constructor function.

```
class Engine {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    Engine(int x, int y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }
  }

  public class Car {
    private final Engine engine;

    public Car(int x, int y) {
      this(new Engine(x, y));
    }

    Car(Engine engine) {
      this.engine = engine;
    }
  }

  public class FastEngine extends Engine {
    private final double a;
    private final double b;

    FastEngine(int x, int y, double a, double b) {
      super(x, y);
      this.a = a;
      this.b = b;
    }
  }

  public class FastCar extends Car {
    public FastCar(int x, int y, double a, double b) {
      super(new FastEngine(x, y, a, b));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Beautiful, although I prefer the CarConfig solution, so I don't have to instantiate the type of engine outside. The constructor might also be doing something necessary for the engine initialization. But your solution is beautiful anyhow! What did you think about Chris's CarConfig solution. And please vote up the question!

Comment: If CarConfig is a useful concept in your domain then by all means. But if it's just there to solve this problem then I would try to avoid introducing an unecessary abstraction. Also, I'd like to avoid anything that involves "instanceof", so at the very least I would add a type parameter to Car so each car can specify it's engine type.